# SharePoint 2013 playing .mp4 from site assets library - about 1200 viewers watching at same time?

Tags: performance, blob-cache, video-richmedia, asset-library

I uploaded an html file with video tag in my site collection root document library(Documents) and then uploaded the .mp4 file in the site assets library with document content type. Its about 42MB. I have the BLOB Cache enabled for this web application set to 10 GB. I have 2 WFE with load balance.
I was wondering if this would scale well if about 1200 get a link to the above html file having a video tag pointing to the url of mp4 file in the asset library.
Should I be doing any more tweaking like IIS bit throttling.
The users are spread in different cites in Canada and this is on premise SharePoint 2013 Server based in Toronto.

Comment: Just FYI, I tend to shift my videos to the cloud. If you have an Office 365 hybrid environment, you should be able to make use of Office 365 Video, which gives you the option to embed your video on SharePoint. Video is a very high performance video service for high volumes of traffic that's intermixed with SP.